# Confidence intervals for extreme value distributions

Tags: r, confidence-interval, extreme-value, weibull-distribution, gumbel-distribution

I have wind data that i'm using to perform extreme value analysis (calculate return levels). I'm using *R* with packages 'evd', 'extRemes' and 'ismev'.

I'm fitting GEV, Gumbel and Weibull distributions, in order to estime the return levels (RL) for some period T.
For the GEV and Gumbel cases, i can get RL's and Confidence Intervals using the *extRemes::return.level()* function.

But for the Weibull case, i need some help to generate the CI's.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This was cross-posted to StackOverflow.